# How to open a URL with POST parameters via external browser in android

Tags: android

I want to POST some token which I receive from a web service, to some URL and open the result in external browser (not webView). To be More clear I want the exact same result as using:

```
String data = "Token=" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8");
mWebView.postUrl(paymentURL, data.getBytes());
```

but open the URL via any web browser installed on the device.

Comment: I see that question is the same as mine, but no solution is provided for that one either.

Comment: There are 4 answers to that question. Did you try any of those suggestions?

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a browser as far as I know.

Comment: None of those answers suit my case.

Comment: I'm trying to send user to bank gateway. I receive a token and a URL from web server and I have to POST that token to the provided URL. I used webView for that purpose but apparently there are some rules or regulations on some app markets which don't allow opening bank gateway inside application. Therefore I have to find a way to open that gateway outside the app.